# How to size icons dynamically within a popup (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following result for my popup, which is ugly.

[image]

My Popup layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <item android:id="@+id/bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/bookmark"
        android:title="bookmark"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_worldmap"
        android:icon="@drawable/world"
        android:title="worldmap"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_timeline"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_timeline"
        android:title="timeline"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/searchintext"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_search"
        android:title="search in text"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_item_icon_size"/>
</menu>
```

My dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="menu_item_icon_size">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The size of my icons differ slightly, but I thought that the size is scaled dynamically.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

### Firstly: The way you are using icons is highly discouraged as per material guidelines.

- I think few `/drawable/...` files have a horizontal margin set, so either change it or verify by keeping `layout_width="wrap_text"` for the item listed above.
- Try to use these guideline.
  https://material.io/components/menus#anatomy

Comment: You are right with "The way you are using icons is highly discouraged". Somethimes I should just read the docu first, before hasting coding. I converted my own designed png's into svg and sized correctly and now it is working fine.

Comment: @mcflysoft Don't reinvent the wheel. Use some good icon library. They are free to use, easy to use, scalable[svg], small in size and widely accepted too! &  now that your code is working fine , can you please close the question by accepting answer?